# How to check if an order has been placed

Tags: php, mysql, validation

I have a pretty simple thing going here. Basic query, but I threw a curve at myself when I decided to go one step further.

Basically it goes like this:

- Check if the user entered a value in the form
- If not, kick out and display a basic error
- If they did then check that value against the database to make sure it is valid/exists
- If it's valid/exists, set a session variable and go the order form
- If not, kick out and display a basic error

What I want to do now is add another check in there, if the user id exists, then I need to check the order status, if they have already order then I want to kick out and Display a simple message letting them know they have already placed the order and it is being processed.  If they have not already ordered then I want to proceed to the order form as above.

The database has a field called "ordered" which has a 1 if they have ordered and a 0 if they haven't ordered yet.

Here is my code that is working, I have tried several things but it keeps blowing up:

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $db_host = 'localhost';
    $db_username = 'xxxxxx';
    $db_password = 'xxxxxxxx';
    $db_name = 'xxxxxxxx';

    mysql_connect( $db_host, $db_username, $db_password) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($db_name); 

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
        /** Check whether the user has filled in the text field "employee_id" */
        if ($_POST['employee_id'] == "") {
            $IdIsEmpty = true;
        }else{ 
            $employee_id = $_POST['employee_id'];  
            if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT employee_id FROM TABLE_2         WHERE         employee_id = '$employee_id'"))){
                // if userid exists
                $_SESSION['emp_id'] = $employee_id;
                header('Location: orderform.php');
            exit;
            }
            $IdNotFound = true;
        }
    }?>

    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <b>Please enter your Employee ID: </b><br><br>
    <form class="" action="index.php" method="post" enctype=
    "multipart/form-data" name="test_form" id="test" accept-charset=
    "utf-8"><input type="text" name="employee_id">
        <?php
        /** Display error messages if "employee_id" field is empty or if ID does not         exist */
        if ($IdIsEmpty) {
            echo ("<br>");
            echo ("<b>Enter your employee ID, please!</b>");
            echo ("<br>");
        }?>
        <?php
        /** Display error messages if "employee_id" field is empty or if ID does not exist */
        if ($IdNotFound) {
            echo ("<br>");
            echo ("<b>Your employee ID not found!</b>");
            echo ("<br>");
        }?>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: stop using `mysql_query()` ! use MySQLi / PDO instead . And for your question, You can just add 1 more query to check. What is your difficulties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides swapping out `mysql_` functions for `mysqli_` like Shivan suggested, you should do this:

- **Escape** any input - you can **never** trust data provided by users, so do
  `$employee_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['employee_id']);`
  In case it is a number, you could also do
  `$employee_id = intval($_POST['employee_id']);`
  Just keep this in mind whenever you use input.
- Now for your problem:

Simply select your `ordered` field in the same query:

```
$order_qry = mysql_query("
    SELECT employee_id, ordered 
    FROM TABLE_2 WHERE employee_id = '$employee_id'
");
if(mysql_num_rows($order_qry)) {
    $order = mysql_fetch_object($order_qry);
    if( ! $order->ordered) { // If not ordered
        // ... do something
    } else { // If already ordered
    // ... tell the client
    }
} else {
// No record found ... error message here
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lukas!  Had to do just a tad of tweaking and getting all my syntax errors fixed (darn curly braces lol!) But your code worked perfect.